# Ansible/Linux: set a group's member list

Tags: ansible

In Ansible/RedHat 7.6, I am looking for a way to clear out a group's member list, and set it to a new list.

Given a user list u1, u2, u3, u4, I want to transform the following entry in /etc/group:

```
mygroup:x:1234:u1,oldu17,oldu19,u3
```

to

```
mygroup:x:1234:u1,u2,u3,u4
```

I do not have access to the old list of group members. Also note that some members may stay in the group (in the above example, u1 and u3 are both in the old and the new list of users)

Background: We have a number of users who get access to certain applications for six months at a time, all starting at the same time (think a semester-long class in a university). Every six months, I have to clear out that group and add the new batch of users.

Of course I can think of a couple ways to accomplish this, but they all seem very hackish.

- I could use lineinfile to edit /etc/group directly.
- I could delete the group and re-create it (but that wouldn't even be idempotent).
- I could somehow parse out the list of old group members, use jinja2 to build a list of all the users to be removed, and all the users to be added.

What I'm looking for is something less crude, and hopefully less complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
---
- hosts: sample-host
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    managed_group: docker
    valid_users:
      - deploy
      - telegraf
  tasks:
    - getent:
        database: group
      # 'getent_group' fact is registered by this module

    - command: "gpasswd -d {{ item | quote }} {{ managed_group | quote }}"
      become: yes
      loop: "{{ actual_users | difference(valid_users) }}"
      vars:
        actual_users: "{{ getent_group[managed_group][2].split(',') }}"
```